# Groovy null safety with multiple assignment

Tags: groovy

Is there a way to "apply" null safety to a multiple assignment from a `null`? For example, this piece of code would obviously throw:

```
// verbosity is for clarity
def (a,b) = new HashMap<String, List<String>>().get("nothing")
```

but it would be neat to have it define `a` and `b` with `null` value.

So far I came up with

```
def (a,b) = new HashMap<String, List<String>>().get("nothing").with {[it?.get(0), it?.get(1)]}
```

But that's really ugly...

Answer (score 2):

This is the safe bet, if you have both missing keys and `null` values:

```
def (a,b) = new HashMap<String, List<String>>().get("nothing") ?: []
```

The next one is from Groovy, but modifies the underlying map (so only
works for mutable maps and whether you are fine with modifying it) and
it only gives the default for missing keys:

```
def (a,b) = new HashMap<String, List<String>>().get("nothing", [])
```

Similar (also from Groovy and also modifying the underlying map):
`withDefault`.  This option is great if you plan to pass the map around
to other places, that would have to deal with the default all over again
(also only defaults for missing keys):

```
def (a,b) = new HashMap<String, List<String>>().withDefault{[]}.get("nothing")
```

And the next one is from Java, but that also only falls back, if the key
is missing:

```
def (a,b) = new HashMap<String, List<String>>().getOrDefault("nothing",[])
```